# Return a Complete sales order where a given item is purchased SQL

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

I'm trying to query our Sales_Order_Line_Item table. We are introducing a new "Tariff" Item code, our sales staff are required to add this code to all orders that have items that start with "WI".  So I need to create a query that will show me any orders that have item codes that start with "WI" but are missing the "Tariff" code.

I can't seem to figure out how to return a list that shows this data.

For simplicity, my Sales_Order_Line_Item Table has these 3 columns:

```
UNIQUE_LINE_ID, SALE_ORDER_#, ITEM_#
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Answer (score 1):

One dirty trick is to use a `case` expression and count the number of times these items appear:

```
SELECT   sale_order_no
FROM     sales_order_line_item
GROUP BY sale_order_no
HAVING   COUNT(CASE WHEN item_code LIKE 'WI%' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
         COUNT(CASE WHEN item_code = 'Tarrif' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: Mureinik, I just replaced the CASE expression (even though it was valid) to avoid confusion for reader. Upvoted.

Comment: @KamilG. I was conflicted on whether to use the shorter syntax or follow suite and have both `case` expressions look the same. After seeing your edit, the code definitely looks better this way.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
select * from Sales_Order_Line_Item
where ItemCode like 'wi%'
and tariff is null
```

Answer (score 0):

If, you want full order details you can use `EXISTS/NOT EXISTS` instead :

```
select so.*
from sales_order_line_item so
where exists (select 1 from sales_order_line_item sol where sol.sale_order_no = s.sale_order_no and sol.item_code LIKE 'WI%') and
      not exists (select 1 from sales_order_line_item sol where sol.sale_order_no = s.sale_order_no and sol.item_code  = 'Tarrif');
```